# A couple GeoExplorer questions

Tags: web-mapping, query, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I just started working with the OpenGeo Suite.  I'd really like to use it for a County web map, but have a couple questions...

1) Is there a way to add a lat/lon or other X/Y location to the URL and have the map center and zoom to the point?  Something like "?lat=46.265&lon=-90.206&zoom=7" at the end of the URL.

2) Is the Query tool available in a published map?  It's not in the [Choose Tools window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERA4Y.jpg) when publishing.

Thanks.

=== UPDATE ===

I will drop part 2 and stick with part 1.

I guess I forgot to mention the crucial bit that I'm working in GeoExplorer.  I did have the tag, but don't fault anybody for missing it.

The bounding box isn't working in GeoExplorer.  I have the map published in an iframe.  Here's a screenshot of the test page without the bbox... i.imgur.com/Wc022Ee.jpg.

Here's a screenshot with the bbox... i.imgur.com/7MES4cn.jpg.  That's just a blank map that hides behind the real map and only shows up when the real map doesn't.

I do have a correct bbox... i.imgur.com/MbAOgVD.jpg in the code.

(I guess I need a higher rep before I can add more direct links, so you'll need to copy paste the image URLs if you want to see them.)

Here's the source behind the page...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { margin:   0; overflow: hidden; }`
      #mapfr { height: 80%; margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; display: block; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Iron County Test Map</h1>
    <iframe id="mapfr"
    src="http://192.168.1.13:8080/geoexplorer/viewer/#maps/1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <p>This is a test map, version T-001.  A disclaimer might go here.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried putting the "?bbox=" at the end of the "src=.../1".

Thanks for any help.  And thanks for the welcome.

Comment: you will get better answers if you only ask one question at a time. see http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! What @iant said. The problem with asking two questions at a time is that you might get answers that are both right and wrong ( i.e. answer to first question is right but the answer to the second one is wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Re 1: You can use the bbox query parameter. It takes coordinates in map projection (Web Mercator by default). So e.g. `?bbox=150000,670000,180000,880000`

Re 2: The Query tool is only available in the composer, not the viewer. In the exported url, change `/viewer` to `/composer` to see it.

Comment: Thanks.  The /composer switch works.  I'll have to decide whether I want users to have that much control over the map, though.  I updated the original post with info about the bounding box.